# Which button was tapped in alert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create alert view like this:

```
UIAlertView* av = [UIAlertView new];
av.title = @"Dealer offer Insurence";
[av addButtonWithTitle:@"YES"];
[av addButtonWithTitle:@"NO"];
```

How can I find out which button was tapped by user?

Answer (score 3):

In what way does [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) fall short? You could even copy code from one of the [many code samples](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html).

Comment: smart ass answer, I like it. :)

Comment: Yeah, a bit harsh perhaps but this kind of question bugs me. Surely it takes longer to write a question than look up the class definition in XCode?